# How to take check box checked value as 2 and unchecked value as 1 in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

How to take `check box` checked value as `2` and unchecked value as `1` in a `DataGridView  cellvaluechanged event` in `VB.NET`.

Here is my scenario

1. Check box column is populated from the database column.
2. If 1 is there respective check box will check while DataGridview loading itself.
3. If user can uncheck the checkbox in DataGridview, I want to take the `checkboxunchecked` value as 2 
   in `DataGridview cellvalue changed event`

Answer (score 0):

One has to wonder why you're posting a question here when you clearly haven't done any proper research.  Proper research MUST include reading the relevant MSDN documentation.  That documentation for the `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` would have told you that the column has `TrueValue` and `FalseValue` properties, which you can set to specify what values in the underlying data correspond to checked and unchecked states respectively.